# Make python dictionary from text file

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

```
man
  cat
  dog
apple
  sun
  friend
```

I have text file in above format I need to make python dictionary:
{'man':'cat, dog', apple: 'sun', 'friend'} words **man** and **apple** have no spaces all the others have 2 spaces before so these two should be keys and words under them should be values.

input_file = "/home/yan/lem.txt"

```
class myDict(dict):

   def __init__(self):
       self = dict()

   def add(self, key, value):
       self[key] = value

lema = myDict()

with open(input_file, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f:
       if not line.startswith("  "):
           lema.add(line.split(), [i for i in f if i.startswith("  ")])
print(lema)
```

Was trying above code, but it gives not what I am expecting.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code in your post. Body code should be formatted with four spaces and inline code should be formatted with backticks.

Comment: is every other line blank?

Comment: no they are not blank

Comment: try if not line.startswith("\t"):

Comment: to have multiple values for a key the values need to be in a list so your dict needs to be {'apple': ['sun', 'friend'], 'man': ['cat', 'dog']} - so its just as easy to do the conversion inline instead of writing a class

Comment: If you created that format you could also take a look at [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: @Yan see my answer hope it can help you fix your class `myDict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you cannot use `self` as your dictionary name, in python it is used to refer your instance variable although it is not reserved keyword.
2. the class function `add()`, try use dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(value) it keeps appends new values to the existing key.
3. override __str__ method which display your expected string format when you invoke `print(lema)`

$ cat test.py

```
    input_file = "lem.txt"
    class myDict(dict):

       def __init__(self):
           self.mydict = dict()

       def add(self, key, value):
           self.mydict.setdefault(key, list()).append(value)

       def __str__(self):
           tmp = list()
           for key, value in self.mydict.items():
               tmp.append("{0}:{1}".format(key, value))
           return "\n".join(tmp)

    lema = myDict()

    with open(input_file) as f:
        for line in f:
           if not line.strip():
               '''skips blank line'''
               continue
           elif not line.startswith(" "):
               key = line.strip()
           elif line.startswith(" "):
               value = line.strip()
               lema.add(key,value)

    print(lema)

The output is:

    $python test.py
    apple:['sun', 'friend']
    man:['cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: man
apple
  sun
  friend   It works perfectly! But what about cases when I have no words  after after word without spaces before?

Answer (score 1):

this will get you what you need:

```
d = {}
k = ''
with open('lem.txt') as f:
    for ln in f.readlines():
        if ln.startswith('  '):
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(ln.strip())
        else:
            k = ln.strip()

print d
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slurp the file into one big string, `s`, and then do something like this:

```
s = """man
  cat
  dog
apple
  sun
  friend"""

d = {}

for line in s.replace("\n  ",',').split('\n'):
    words = line.split(',')
    d[words[0]] = words[1:]

>>> d
{'man': ['cat', 'dog'], 'apple': ['sun', 'friend']}
```

To get a feel for what is happening here:

```
>>> s.replace("\n  ",',')
'man,cat,dog\napple,sun,friend'
```